# I migrated WP to another domain and now I get a double navbar

Tags: wordpress, iframe, migration

I migrated my WP website to another domain, I am using an animation I made on Animate CC and used and Iframe to placed it. I am working with DIVI and Elementor.

Now, when I click from the animation, I get a double nav bar and I have no idea why. But when I go from the menu, everything is fine.

Does someone know how to fix this? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling DIVI, elementor and other plugins but nothing works. I have also changed the links  of the animation.

This is the website:

https://psychotherapie-couple-famille-lausanne.ch/accueil/

I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are loading that page in an iframe. 
for example, by clicking an image it opened this page https://psychotherapie-couple-famille-lausanne.ch/therapies/therapie-individuelle/ in iframe.

Edit that page and hide header for that page from divi settings or put this CSS code for that page. you will see custom css option on that page.

```
div#page-container {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
header#main-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hello! 
Thank you for your answer. I tried but it removed the header also when you go from the menu.

Comment: add it on a specific page which is loading inside iframe